# Shift Register not working in Verilog HDL

Tags: verilog, hdl, shift-register

I'm trying to design a 64-bit Shift register in Verilog HDL but when I test the code with a testbench, all the bits are zeros. I don't know where I'm going wrong. Here is my code and the test bench result:

```
module ShiftRegister (shift_out, clk, shift_in, rst); //module ports
 parameter n = 64; //Parameter n declared to store 64
 input rst;
 input [n-1:0] shift_in; //64-bit input shift_in
 input clk; //Input clock
 output [n-1:0] shift_out; //64-bit output shift_out
 reg [n-1:0] ff; //64-bit flipflop
  assign shift_out = ff [n-1:0]; //give the output of the 64th bit
  //The operation of verilog: 
   always @ (posedge clk or posedge rst) //Always at the rising edge of the clock
   begin
     if (rst) begin
     ff <= 0;
   end else begin
     ff <= ff << 1;  //Shift bits to the left by 1
     ff[0] <= shift_in; //Take the input bits and give it to the first flipflop
   end
   end
 endmodule


 module ShiftRegister_tb; //Module shiftRegister_tb
  parameter n = 64; //Parameter n declared to store 64
  reg [n-1:0] shift_in; //64-bit register input shift_in
  reg clk, rst; //register clock
  wire [n-1:0] shift_out; //64-bit wire output shift_out
  ShiftRegister DUT(shift_out, clk, shift_in,rst); //Calling the module
   initial
   begin
     clk = 0; //clock = 0 initally
     rst = 1;
     shift_in = 64'd34645767785344; //Random decimal number to test the code 
     #100;
     rst = 0;
     #50_000 $finish;
   end   
  always #50 clk =~clk; //invert the clock input after 50ps
 endmodule //ShiftRegister testbench
```

[image: Testbench Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `ff[0] <= shift_in;`, you are trying to assign a 64-bit variable to 1-bit variable. Since you use a even number (`64'd34645767785344`) for `shift_in` in your testbench, its LSB is `0`. Therefore, you keep inserting 0 to `ff`.

Make your `shift_in` input 1-bit and change your testbench such that you will give 1-bit at a time as input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what I can also do is send input bits like one at a time? i've tried doing it this way but it doesn't work as expected. Is there a way I can just insert 64-bits? like i'm looking to input random binary like 10101011110111 etc.

Comment: Yes. Then you need to define a way to "initialize" your register. For example, define an input port named `load`. Then you can initialize your register with making load 1 and giving your 64-bit input. When `load` is 0, your circuit should shift `ff`.

Comment: When I send a 1-bit input '1', then it shifts. But i'm not able to send another bit after that like it doesn't input the, `shift_in = 1` `#10` `shift_in = 0` `#10` `shift_in = 1` , It only takes in the first '1' and not the other bits